# Ember rc 6 not recognizing Handlebars rc 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get started out learning Ember.js and I'm receiving this error right when the page loads:

```
Assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars version 1.0.0-rc.4. 
Include a SCRIPT tag in the HTML HEAD linking to the Handlebars file before 
you link to Ember.
```

However, I went to the [Ember.js 'About' page](http://emberjs.com/about/) and downloaded the starter kit. It came with the following files:

- ember-1.0/0-rc.6.js
- handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js
- jquery-1.9.1.js

I'm doing this in an ASP MVC 3 project, so there is some Razor syntax here, but this is my `_Layout.cshtml` file. I current don't have anything in the Home `Index` page, so this is literally all the HTML that will be loaded onto the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>Bootstrap/Ember.js Sample Application</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this issue. Did not know you needed to place the handlebars script before ember. Declarations now look like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```